# add post meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I am trying to add post-meta value and after this update query and after this get_post_meta value . but add_post_meta does not work .

```
<?php add_post_meta($post_id, 'Product_Year', trim( $_POST['Product_Year'])); ?>
  <?php update_post_meta($post_id, 'Product_Year', trim( $_POST['Product_Year'])); ?>

echo $year=get_post_meta($post_id , 'Product_Year',true );
```

Comment: you can value GET or not in `$post_id`?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use `add_post_meta` and `update_post_meta` for same meta_key.

You can simply use `update_post_meta` function and this will 
**add** if the meta_key does not exist and will **update** if meta_key exists.

Comment: Yes@ good, but let me know how can work on edit module

Comment: Please clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

Add last parameter, refer this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

```
add_post_meta($post_id, 'Product_Year', trim( $_POST['Product_Year']), true);
```

Comment: this is not working right now @ any other help@ how can i insert  form field input value in  database